# how to set an item Image field

Tags: powershell-extensions, media-library

Using Sitecore PowerShell Extensions I can set an item's text properties but an Image property cannot be set:

[image]

In the screenshot above, setting the Title property worked but none of the attempts at setting the Featured Image worked.

However from Content Editor when I specify a relative media library path, it works:

[image]

Is it possible to set an image field value with a media library item using Sitecore PowerShell Extensions? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the [docs](https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/working-with-items), you can do something as simple as the following:

```
$homeItem = Get-Item -Path "master:/content/home"
$homeItem.Image = Get-Item -Path "master:\media library\logo"
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense since the Image field is getting an actual item and not just text. Thanks!